# Connect title of each plot with the do loop variable

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the following line in gnuplot to plot 4 graphs from the file rdf.xvg

```
plot for [n=2:5]  "rdf.xvg" u 1:n  ti 'graph'.n.' wL=0.25'
```

The problem is at the title. I want the title of each graph to say

```
"graph LL wL=0.25"
"graph RR wL=0.25"
"graph LR wL=0.25"
"graph To wL=0.25"
```

I think the solution is the connection of n variable with the LL, RR, LR, To with an if statement like

if n=2 then ti 'graph LL wL=0.25' etc

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a string which contains the different words. You can access them using the `word` function (first word is index with `1`):

```
labels = "LL RR LR To"
plot for [n=2:5]  "rdf.xvg" u 1:n  ti 'graph '.word(labels, n-1).' wL=0.25'
```

Comment: I would love to do this but I am new and I am not familiar with this!!